# How to use Mapped Types with React.useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, mapped-types

I'm trying to figure out how to use `Mapped Types` with `React UseState`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  type MapType = {
    [id: number]: string[];
  };

  let id_sab: number = 1;
  let sab: string[] = ["a", "b"]

  let scde: string[] = ["c", "d", "e"];
  let id_scde: number = 2

  const [map, setMap] = React.useState<MapType>({
      [id_sab] : sab 
  });


  React.useEffect(() => {

      // How to add a new key-value pair map[id_scde] = scde ?

    setMap(map => [...map, map[id_scde] = scde]) // This gives error. How to do it correctly?
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it should be `[id_sab]: sab`

Comment: also `setMap((map) => ({...map, [id_scde]: scde}));`

Comment: @wonderflame Yes. For the the initial settings   `const [map, setMap] = React.useState<MapType>({
      [id_sab] :sab
  });`
works fine.  But `  React,useEffect(() => {
    setMap(map => [...map, map[id_scde] : scde])
  },[])
` give error

Comment: answered in the other comment

Comment: Yes: `  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMap(map => ({...map, [id_scde] : scde}))
  },[])
` works fine. Thank you very much. If you put it in an answer, I can flag it as correct. thank you

Comment: Yes, I will write up an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the react or typescript. The issue is that you are using invalid javascript syntax.

In the initial value you are assigning the property to an object, therefore, you should use `:` instead of `=`.

```
{
      [id_sab]: sab 
}
```

in the `setMap` you are setting an array; however, your type is an object. Thus, you have to change the syntax to:

```
setMap((map) => ({...map}));
```

And to change `id_scde` property you should use the following syntax:

```
setMap((map) => ({...map, [id_scde]: scde}));
```

Comment: and ...to delete an element? This: `  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMap(map => ({...map, map.delete[id_sab]}))
  },[])
` does not work

Comment: ```const {[id_sab]: removedKey, ...restMap} = map;setMap(restMap);```

Comment: wow.... I didn't think about it.... Clever: "tag" the key to remove as `removedKey` and then keep the rest. Thank you very much again!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `MapType` is object but you are trying to call it as array.

You need to use    `setMap((map) => ({ ...map, [id_scde]: scde }));`

Also `MapType` is a object which mean that key can be only `string`

P.S It's better to use `Record<string, string[]>` for `MapType`